# Angular production build error why I am getting ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

When I am trying to build ng serve --prod,
I am getting some error below:
$ ng build --prod error

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown/bs-dropdown.module' in 'C:\Users\MadOrWat\Desktop\gsipKOtakUI\pro\sameProdGsip\src\app'

following are the version of my current app
[image: Version Reference]

and Also I am trying with ng add @angular/pwa --project app

Where I am facing some other issue 
Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bridge of ngx-bootstrap on rxjs is facing some issue. You must try do an explicit npm install of bootstrap preferably the stable/latest version and it should work fine.

I did the below and it worked fine:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1
```

All the best,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Found this [issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4308) in *ngx-bootstrap* github repository:

> ngx bootstrap error with Angular -v6.0.0 and rxjs -v6.0.0

An interesting [comment](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4308#issuecomment-387380762) in there saying:

> rxjs v6 has several breaking changes including simplifying import points for operators. Try installing `rxjs-compat`, which adds back those import paths until the code has been migrated.

Give it a try, hope it will help you.